# Django supervisor+Gunicorn+Nginx - ImportError: No module named backend.wsgi

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, supervisord

I am getting the following error log where backend of course is the name of my Django project. I looked at other related Q/A on SO but could not get something relevant.

```
[2015-07-12 12:18:04 +0000] [17089] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-07-12 12:18:04 +0000] [17089] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8002 (17089)
[2015-07-12 12:18:04 +0000] [17089] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-07-12 12:18:04 +0000] [17098] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17098
[2015-07-12 12:18:04 +0000] [17098] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named backend.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named backend.wsgi
[2015-07-12 12:18:04 +0000] [17098] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 17098)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 189, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 174, in run
    self.manage_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
    self.spawn_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 541, in spawn_workers
    time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 214, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/backend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

If you need some other info let me know.
EDIT:
**supervisor.conf**

```
[program:%(PROJECT_NAME)s]
command=%(PROJECT_PATH)s/start_gunicorn.bash
directory=%(PROJECT_PATH)s
user=www-data
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=%(PROJECT_PATH)s/logs/supervisorconf.log
```

**start_gunicorn.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Starts the Gunicorn server
set -e

# Activate the virtualenv for this project
%(ACTIVATE)s

# Start gunicorn going
exec gunicorn %(PROJECT_NAME)s.wsgi:application -c %(PROJECT_PATH)s/gunicorn.conf.py
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you also post your suporvisor config for backend.

Comment: `start_gunicorn.bash` is also needed I guess

Comment: @jgadelange : I have put that up too. I am following this config - https://github.com/ashokfernandez/Django-Fabric-AWS

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my django + react + gunicorn project which is built with docker.

The real cause was the location of a module containing a WSGI application. The command which starts the gunicorn server is expected to run [inside the Django main project directory](https://location%20of%20a%20module%20containing%20a%20WSGI%20application).

The correct workflow of `start_gunicorn.bash` shall looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Starts the Gunicorn server
set -e

# Activate the virtualenv for this project
%(ACTIVATE)s

# Change directory
cd course 

# Start gunicorn going
exec gunicorn course.wsgi
```